# Tmux [exited] on startup

Tags: ubuntu, tmux

I recently installed Tmux and became really glad for it. All of a sudden I though it would start throwing an error when I try to create a new session from within my terminal:

```
tmux new -s my-session
```

will cause the application to crash and only return `[exited]` and put the following on the next command line: `62;9;c`.

Being new to Tmux I have no idea how to fix this issue. Does anybody recognize this error and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removing

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"
```

from the configuration fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Assuming (1) you're on a Mac, (2) have `brew` installed and (3) would like to keep using that option, you can just install the missing plugin: `brew install reattach-to-user-namespace`

Comment: I had the exact same problem, however, I realised in my case I simply had a session still running, so all I did was `tmux attach` and my problem was fixed